# invalid number of arguments in "proxy_pass" directive

Tags: nginx

У меня стоит nginx-proxy, запускаю проверку конфигурационного файла, выдается ошибка:

> nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "proxy_pass" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/%%%%%%.save:11
>   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Почему ругается?

---

из комментария:

```
server {
  listen 8083;
  server_name %%%%;
  proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/bb/%%%%.log upstreamlog;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/bb/%%%%.log error;
  location / {
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8091;
  }
  location /health-check/ {
    access_log off;
    return 200;
  }
}
```

Comment: Конфиг не покажите?

Comment: server {
        listen 8083;
        server_name bank.megafon.ru;

        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/bb/bb_megafon-access-megafon.log upstreamlog;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/bb/bb_megafon-error-megafon.log error;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8091;
        }

        location /health-check/ {
              access_log off;
              return 200;
        }
}

Comment: @ИльяДьяков, я дополнил ответ по результатам вашего комментария. кстати, код лучше приводить не в комментариях, а сразу в вопросе, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: GrayHoax а ты где работаешь?

Comment: Привет, коллега)

Answer (score 4):

> nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "proxy_pass" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/bank.megafon.ru.save:11

перевод: неправильное количество аргументов у директивы *proxy_pass* в 11-й строке файла `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/bank.megafon.ru.save`.

у этой директивы должен быть [ровно один аргумент](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).

---

но суффикс файла (`.save`) наводит на мысль, что этот файл — всего лишь копия какого-то другого, сохранённая не там, где надо: все файлы в каталоге `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` прочитываются как части конфигурации.

---

**дополнение после появления в вопросе текста файла**:

> `proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8091;`

здесь забыт протокол в *url-е* — `http://...`, `https://...` или ещё какой-нибудь.